# how to prove by recurrency a limit

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have no idea how to go about this.

> prove by recurrence that $\lim_{x->0}\frac{(ax+1)^{n}-1}{x}=na$

Thanks.

Comment: it is the derivative of $(ax+1)^n$ at $0$ which is $na$

Comment: i should use the proof by recurrence to solve it

Answer (score 2):

$(ax+1)^{n+1}-(ax+1)^n
=(ax+1)^{n}((ax+1)-1)
=ax(ax+1)^{n}
$
so
$\dfrac{(ax+1)^{n+1}-1}{x}-\dfrac{(ax+1)^n-1}{x}
=\dfrac{(ax+1)^{n+1}-1-((ax+1)^n-1)}{x}
=\dfrac{(ax+1)^{n+1}-(ax+1)^n)}{x}
=a(ax+1)^n
$.

Since
$\lim_{x \to 0} (ax+1)^n
=1$,
$\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{(ax+1)^{n+1}-1}{x}-\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{(ax+1)^n-1}{x}
=a
$.

Starting with $n=1$,
$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{(ax+1)^1-1}{x}
=\lim_{x \to 0}a
=a$,
so by induction,
$\lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{(ax+1)^n-1}{x}
=na
$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(ax+1)^{n}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(0)=na(a0+1)^{n-1}=na$$

Comment: Gimusi, you have an extra a in the second step $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(ax+1)^{n}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\color{red}{a}\,\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$  the a comes normally from the derivative of the function $(ax+1)^n \to an(ax+1)^{n-1}$

Comment: ops yes of course, just a typo from a different approach! thanks I fix

Comment: @Isham Thanks a lot for the appreciation!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a high-school identity:
$$(ax+1)^n-1=(ax+\not1-\not1)\bigl((ax+1)^{n-1}+\dots+(ax+1)+1\bigr), $$
$$\text{so }\qquad\frac {(ax+1)^n-1}{x} = a\bigl((\underbrace{ax+1)^{n-1}+\dots+(ax+1)+1}_{n \text{ terms}}\bigr)\quad\text{tends to }an.$$